# Openvpn client on local server

Tags: debian, openvpn

My headless server established VPN connection with VPN server. How can I connect to ip website provide by VPN server?

What I want:

[image: What I want]]

I don't want direct connectiom:

[image: I don't want direct connection]]

Any opinion will be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for handdrawn graphics. :D // Can you set up routes on the OpenVPN server?

Comment: I can't. I only have .ovpn file, cert, key, login and password to establish connection. That's all I have :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicate you cannot change the server, you must use NAT. That is because the server needs to know where to send the response to and it only knows about the VPN client itself, your local server. It doesn’t know about PCs reachable via the VPN client.

On your local server, you need to enable NAT on the OpenVPN interface. This can be accomplished by using a script. One possible hook is `--route-up`. Remember to change `--script-security` appropriately. The commands you need to run is `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $THE_OPENVPN_INTERFACE -j MASQUERADE`. Since IPTables allows everything be default, further configuration is optional. You should probably also add a `--route-pre-down` (or similar) script to remove the IPTables rule again.

Routing can be enabled by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`, `net.ipv4.ip_forward` needs to be `1`. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` makes the change effective immediately. `sysctl.conf` is for persistence across reboots.

On your router, you need to set up a static route to the destination (the network accessible via VPN) with the gateway being your local server (the VPN client). Be aware: Because you’re on the same network as the gateway, your router may send redirects. You may not be able to change this behavior. Your OS has to accept redirects. But first try it without additional setup.

You may wish to properly firewall your local server because a malicious actor with access to the VPN server could gain access to your local network otherwise.

Comment: I have problem with static route. What will be IPv4-Gateway? I think that will be `peer` of VPN connection: `172.16.120.77`. Is it true? I tried with many another IP's which could be IPv4-Gateway, but I am getting 1003 error in my web browser all the time. How be sure that this is proper IP this gateway?

Comment: No, the gateway is your local server. Also called “next hop”, it must be directly reachable through a local interface—in this case, your router’s LAN interface. It’s exactly like your diagram shows. If your local server currently does not have a static IP address, now is the time to set it up.

Comment: I will make two part comment.  I modified my `.ovpn` file, I added `script-security 2`, with `3` I tried too ;) I wrote script: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE`. I started vpn connection: `sudo openvpn --config /path_to/file.ovpn --route-up /path_to/script.sh`. Logs says that connection is established correctly. When I typed `sudo iptables -t nat` I see that new rule in nat table was created :) Script works. I uncommented `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Then: `sudo sysctl -p`. `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` says `1`.

Comment: Part2: I created static route in my router. `Target` is my local IP. `Gateway` is server local IP.  I uncommented on my computer `net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1` in  `/etc/sysctl.conf` . Again, `sudo sysctl -p` to save changes. Then I typed website IP to my web browser and still I have 1003 error.;( Any idea why it could not work?

Comment: But the target is not your local IP. The target is what you’re trying to reach: The remote network. Your server also does not need to _send_ redirects. Your _client PC_ may need to _accept_ redirects.

Comment: 1)Static route should be: Target: my static external IP: 37.190.X.X and IPv4-Gateway: local IP of server: 192.168.1.102? I don't understand why. Where in my whole configuration is said that signal should be forwarded to me(client PC). How website IP 1.0.X.X can work? 2) By "my computer" I thought about client PC, not server. Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Think again: What are you trying to reach? It’s the network inside the VPN. That’s the target. Not some external or internal or whatever single IP address. A network. You’ll have to find it out yourself, for example by looking at the server’s routing table while the VPN is connected.